# Querying entities with nested many to many relations

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have this problem since I started using Laravel. When I want to have an entity which doesn't have a certain nested relation, for the life of me and countless hours, I couldn't get it through eloquent has() method. I normally do this through Fluent and left joins.

Lets say there are three models with one pivot (user_persona) which only carries the ids of related models;

## Example

```
| User    |       | Persona    |       | Category    |
-----------       --------------       ---------------
| user_id | -M-M- | persona_id | -O-M- | category_id |
-----------       --------------       | persona_id  |
                                       ---------------
```

### Relationships

#### User

```
function personas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Persona', 'user_persona', 'user_id', 'persona_id');
}
```

#### Persona

```
function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'persona_id');
}
```

### Problem

Now one can get a user with a persona with a certain category through:

```
User::has('personas.categories', '>=', 1, 'and', function ($q) use ($cid) {
    $q->where('category.category_id', '=', $cid)
})->first();
```

But I can't get all the other users which don't have that relation with the same category through;

```
User::has('personas.categories', '=', 0, 'and', function ($q) use ($cid) {
    $q->where('category.category_id', '=', $cid)
})->get();
```

Eloquent will return users including all those which have any other relation with personas. Those users will also be included which match the excluding relation but also have another relation which doesn't match it. Only those will be filtered which get all their related personas to match the condition.

#### Intended Similar Query in Fluent

All in all, I want it to return the same results as the following query:

```
SELECT
    user.*
FROM
    user u
LEFT JOIN user_persona up ON u.user_id = up.user_id AND up.persona_id IN 
        (SELECT persona_id FROM persona_category WHERE category_id = ?)
WHERE
    up.persona_id IS NULL;
```

#### Current Eloquent Generated Query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            `persona`
        INNER JOIN `user_persona` ON `persona`.`persona_id` = `user_persona`.`persona_id`
        WHERE
            `user_persona`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id`
        AND (
            SELECT
                count(*)
            FROM
                `persona_category`
            WHERE
                `persona_category`.`persona_id` = `persona`.`persona_id`
            AND `persona_category`.`category_id` = ?
        ) = ?
    ) >= ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using **Laravel Eloquent ORM Relationships** 
try this 
in User model

```
public function personas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Persona','user_persona');
}
```

in Persona model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_persona');
}
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category','user_persona');
}
```

in Category model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_persona');
}
public function personas()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Persona','user_persona');
}
```

now you can use it like below

```
$user->personas->categories
  //or
$personas->users-categories
  //or
$personas->categories
  //or
$category->users
  //or
$category->personas
  //or
$category->personas->users
  // and many other relationship queries by Eloquent
```

and by **eager loading** you can save yourself form n+1 query problem

```
$user=User::with('persona')->find(1)->get();
```

now it will return the user and its relationship details and data or persona..

you can refer from [here - Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) and [Eloquent Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: No I am using them, I have just not mentioned them here. I'll add them, but it was more of a, is it even possible or am I not getting it question.

Comment: as i'm getting your question, what you are doing is possible by these relationship very easily. you do not have to query usign Model::has or something like that..

Comment: I have same relationships in models. But what you propose wouldn't that cost more?

Comment: I have over 100k users to deal with

Comment: If that is so then you can use laravel's eager loading like **User::with('persona')->find(1)->get();** ... refer here **http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading**

Comment: Thanks for your insight. But eager loading doesn't allow conditions over the data set thus I'll have to check for them in code. Hell it includes even those models which don't have that relation. The has() really saves me this hassle which applies the conditions on the result set. Also I only want the user models not the others.

Comment: well further you can also check **Eloquent Scopes** for your custom queries with eager loading